# Обход cloudflare на сайте https://www.coingecko.com/

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, cloudflare

На данном сайте присутствует защиты cloudflare - https://www.coingecko.com/ Как мне обойти эту защиту, желательно без selenium. Меня пропускало, когда я отправлял запрос с куки __cf_bm, тогда было все нормально, я каждые примерно 30 мин, брал вручную из браузера этот куки, но спустя несколько часов парсинга, этот способ перестал работать, то есть при отправке этого куки меня не пропускал cloudflare. Пробовал использовать cfscrape, aiocfscrape, а также cloudscraper - ничего не помогает, хотя может я как-то неправильно отправляю запрос с помощью этих утилит, но это мало вероятно, так как все сделал по примерам из просторов Интернета.

Comment: Использовать апи

Comment: У сайта api платный

Comment: значит они не хотят, чтобы ты парсил их сайт безлимитно. Либо плати, либо нарушай ToS. Ты выбрал нарушать, помогать тебе вряд ли будут.

Answer (score -3):

- Попробуй там зарегистрироваться и посмотри с какого айпи придет письмо.
- Это будет реальный айпи-адрес сервера.
- Смотришь открыты ли 80 и 443 порты у этого айпи, смотришь сертификаты, если он самый, то идем далее.
- В `/etc/hosts` вписываешь `coingecko.com <реальный ip сервера>`
- Парсишь сайт.

Comment: Я зарегался на сайте, пришло письмо, посмотрел заголовки, ip узнал, но ни 80 ни 443 порты не открыты

Comment: а минусы что ставишь? кто тебе после этого помогать будет? ну читай еще узнать реайльный айпи-адрес сервера или плати деньги тем кто знает. всего хорошего

Comment: Добавил ip в hosts, не работает. Я не ставил минусы